# Unable to use .then in express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Express framework and learning, I'm having a problem using `.then`. The problem is I have 2 functions and I want the first one to complete before the second to start executing. I'm exporting the modules.

```
var ubm = require('./userBasic');
```

There are 2 functions `setUserData` and `showUserId`, the `showUserId` must execute only after setUserData has performed its operation.

```
var userId = ubm.setUserData(userName,userEmail,userDOB,moment);

userId.then(ubm.showUserId(userId));
```

Below are the 2 functions:

```
    module.exports = {
                    setUserData: function (userName,userEmail,userDOB,moment){
                              //Performing database activities
                       return userId;
                    }
                    showUserId: function (userId){
                       console.log(userId);
                    }
    }
```

When i run it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Like I said I'm very new and learning and was unable to figure out the solution. I did some google search and got a brief about `promise`, but I don't know how to implement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using promises

```
module.exports = {
  setUserData: function(userName, userEmail, userDOB, moment) {
                 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                   //db stuff
                   reject(error);
                   resolve(userId);
                 });
               },
  showUserId: function(userId) {
                  console.log(userId);
              };
  };
```

So in your execution you would write

```
ubm.setUserData(username, usereEmail, userDOB, moment)
.then((data) => {
  showUserId(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

A couple of things to note is that in this instance you could just log data without the need for another function like

```
ubm.setUserData(username, usereEmail, userDOB, moment)
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Whatever value you pass into resolve() will be returned as well as you pass errors into reject().

Comment: The problem is `showUserId` is getting executed before `setUserData` and logging `undefined`.

Comment: I tried removing `reject` and so the above problem occurred and now that I've added `reject(error)` it says `error` is `undefined`. What if it don't wan to throw any error?

Comment: Sorry about that, reject is to handle errors, if you handle them. Yes, leave out that bit and it will work and leave out the .catch portion

Comment: By mistake I forgot to include `promise`. It worked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, look into promises. They can help reduce in callback hell